# jpg2000 to jpg with pgmagick on Windows comes out as grayscale

Tags: python, image, jpeg2000

I need convert/load jpg2000 images (24 BIT RGBI True Color) to png/jpg for further usage and struggled quite a bit to get them loaded at all on windows. Succeeded with a pgmagic installation on windows, but the RGBI images come out as grayscale.

Output image generated with:

```
from pgmagick import Image
img = Image("path")
img.write('output.jpg')
```

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: You can probably check the properties of img to see if it thinks it's greyscale at that point or not, i.e. whether something has gone wrong in the load or the save. Can you try this with command line magick to see if that has the same problem?

Comment: But unless someone can spot that you've done something wrong, this is probably a bug report for pymagick or imagemagick.

Comment: can you suggest a alternative from pymagick for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

I had to use osgeo:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from PIL import Image

dataset = gdal.open("path", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
img = dataset.ReadAsArray()
img_trnsp = img.transpose()
final_image = Image.fromarray(img_trnsp)
```